# How do mining pools figure out the hashing speed of the connected miners?

Tags: mining-pools, hashpower, mining-pool-shares, pool-payout-methods

How do mining pools figure out the hashing speed of the miners connected to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since pools only receive successfully calculated shares they must approximate your actual hashrate based on the number of shares submitted.

Assuming we're talking about difficulty 1 shares, you should be able to approximate hashrate via `H = S * 2^32 / T` where `H = hashrate`, `S = shares submitted` and `T = time in seconds`. Your estimate will be more accurate for larger values of T.

It takes approximately 2^32 hashes to find a share and each share has a 1/D (D = difficulty) chance of correctly solving the block. From that, with some simple math, you should be able to calculate almost every important thing about mining.